# Sphere to Sphere Collision Detection

Tags: collision, detection

Does anyone know where to start when it comes to Sphere to Sphere Collision Detection, I've been looking online and can't find any answers. If anyone knows how to program C++ Sphere to Sphere Collision Detection, and can provide an example.

Comment: Do you search a formula / the math behind it? On the fly, I could find this, but it's in German. When we talk about collision detection, we probably don't need the case "Sphere #1 lies within sphere #2" ;-)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7EEL8CHL5pk and this is in English https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPzyNOHY3A4    However, if your question is how to program a sphere at all, then I could provide Code in VB.NET....

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zeLqLlDU1gKAEO8miG9FwGXur9xROFle/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this is the code I got if anyone has any pointers